# Glide load thumbnail not working

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using Glide to load thumbnail from videos but it doesn't seem to be working on my app. The ImageView is just empty for some reason.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(target);
```

I added a listener, so I can figure out what is wrong but the Exception thrown is null.

I tried using ThumbnailUtils using the same url because I thought there might be something wrong with it but the thumbnail loads fine.

Anyone experiencing the same? I'm using a Nexus 7 (6.0.1)

Answer (score 7):

Even i stumbled upon the same situation. Somehow from the uri its not loading the image unless create a file instance using local file path. So to make it work i used it like below

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)).into(icon);
```

In the doc they are using the same approach. You can refer here : [Glide - Videos](https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos)

Apart from that i also noticed unusual behaviour of using the cache. If you are using cache strategy as **DiskCacheStrategy.ALL or DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE** it doesn't load the thumbnail but if i am using **DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT** it works. Hope it helps

Comment: i'm using this solution from long time but still i'm searching for getting `thumb` for `audioFile`

Comment: It doesn't work at 3.7.0 version. Also I can't use the latest version due to another glide bug. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in Glide documentation, this feature is only available for  **videos stored locally** on the device.

Also, you should use a path like `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/example_video.mp4`. Adding `file:///` before this path won't work out either.

You can find more informations here : https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

Cheers !

Comment: yup. I am loading thumbnail from videos in the device SD card, unfortunately it doesn't load at all

Comment: As far as i'm concerned, i don't use the .asBitmap() option. But i guess you already tried everything on that ... Is it linked to the Android version maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use override, which surely works:

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(url)
         .crossFade()
         .override(width, height)
         .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(mcontext)
                .applyDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
                .load(videourl)
                .into(thumbnailimg);
```

Try using this code

Answer (score 0):

```
@BindingAdapter("videoThumbnailFromUrl")
fun setImageFromVideoUrl(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {
   val thumb = 10000L
   val options = RequestOptions().frame(thumb)
   Glide.with(imageView.context).load(url).apply(options).placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder).into(imageView)
}
```